# Twitter no longer working after Cocos2d 2.0 upgrade

Tags: twitter, uiviewcontroller, cocos2d-iphone

I have a project that uses the Twitter API to Tweet the users high score. That project is written using Cocos2d v1.1 and everything is working fine. I recently started a new project using Cocos2d v2.0 and attempted to use the same code from my other project to incorporate the same Twitter functionality but the viewcontroller will not appear when the Tweet button is pressed. Below is the code I'm using...

```
if ([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]) // Check if twitter is setup and reachable
    {
        CCLOG(@"Can Tweet");
        TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

        // set initial text
        NSString *theTweet = @"The message..."];
        [tweetViewController setInitialText:theTweet];

        // setup completion handler
        tweetViewController.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {
            if(result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone) {
                // the user finished composing a tweet

            } else if(result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {
                 // the user cancelled composing a tweet
            }
            [viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        };

        // present view controller
        [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:viewController.view];
        [viewController presentViewController:tweetViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
else
{
    // Twitter account not configured, inform the user
    NSLog(@"You can't send a tweet right now, make sure your device has an internet connection and you have at least one Twitter account setup");
}
```

I've discovered that "openGLView" is now depreciated and I have replaced it with "view". This still does not work. The method is firing though. I've included a CCLOG that return the string "Can Tweet" and that is appearing in the output window. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get this to work. Let me know if I need to provide more information.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code in cocos2d 2.0

```
AppController * app = (((AppController*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate));

        TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

        [tweetViewController setInitialText:string];

        [tweetViewController setCompletionHandler:^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                {
                    if (result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone)
                    {
                        //successful
                        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PPTweetSuccessful" object:nil];

                    }
                    else if(result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled)
                    {
                        //Cancelled
                    }
                }

                [app.navController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

                [tweetViewController release];
            });

        }];

        [app.navController presentModalViewController:tweetViewController animated:YES];
```